# VBA set a range from one cell to a cell with a certain value

Tags: excel, vba

I am looking for a way to set the range from Q7 to the cell that contains the string (blank). This is what I have and it is not working. I am still very new to this and I am unsure what to do.

```
Sub MatrixRange()
Dim blankCell As Range
Set blankCell = Cells.Find(what:="(blank)")
range (Cells(7,"Q"),Cells(blankCell,"Q"))
End Sub
```

Comment: `Range(Cells(7,"Q"), blankCell)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not too clear exactly what you want to do, but this might be close:

```
Sub MatrixRange()
    Dim blankCell As Range, rng as Range, ws As Worksheet

    Set ws = ActiveSheet
    Set blankCell = ws.Cells.Find(what:="(blank)")
    If Not blankCell Is Nothing Then
        Set rng = ws.Range(ws.Cells(7,"Q"), ws.Cells(blankCell.Row,"Q")) 'Q but same row as blankCell
        'or 
        Set rng = ws.Range(ws.Cells(7,"Q"), blankCell) 'Q7 to blankCell
        'do something with rng
    End If
End Sub
```